# Optimal file divide

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having problem with creating "best" file dividing.

For example this is my list :

[image: List]

Structure :

```
 Type;Amount
```

Amount of records in file -

```
178816 (34233+18876+...)
```

Now I ask user about how may files he want to create, for example 3:

```
 178816 / 3 = 59605
```

Possibilities :

```
 34233+18876=53109  or  34233+18876+32000=85109
```

So since 53109 is closest to 59605 then I'm putting it in First file.

Then I want to create next one so I had to skip (A;34233 and G;18876) because I 
already use them

So now I want this :

```
(178816 - 53109) / (3 - 1)
```

And find closes one again etc.

Can someone help me accomplish this ?

This is what I have for now :

```
        for (int i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++)
        {
            mid = (sum-closest) / (filesAmount - i);

            closest = ammountAfterSum.Aggregate((x, y) => Math.Abs(x - mid) < Math.Abs(y - mid) ? x : y);

            MessageBox.Show(closest.ToString());

        }
```

Comment: Your question has a lot of assumptions you probably know the answer to but we don't. Are you saying that you got 34233 elements of type A, 18876 elements of type G, 32000 of type R and so on? And then you need to split these up into, as an example, 3 files "the best way"? Do you have to keep all elements of the same type in one file or can you split for instance the A elements over two files (combined with other elements as well)?

Comment: also can you reorder?  ie can you have A,G and Ns in file 1 say?

Comment: Types has to be divide is this order so for example I cant have A and H in file1, it has to be A,G or A,G,R

Comment: Whole type must be in one file, I can't divide types.

Comment: Please edit those details into the question then so that someone knowledgeable in bin-packing type problems have all the information needed to perhaps help you.